# TypeScript string is "not assignable" to a union of string literals type. Why not?

Tags: typescript

I've created a type called `Direction` that is a union of the strings `'LEFT'` and `'RIGHT'`, but tsc doesn't want me to assign a `'LEFT'` string to it. Here's the minimal example:

```
type Direction = 'LEFT' | 'RIGHT';
class Duckling {
    direction: Direction;

    constructor() {
        // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Direction'
        this.direction = ['LEFT', 'RIGHT'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
    }
}
```

What wrong idea about TypeScript types do I have? Shouldn't `this.direction` allow a string if it's the `'LEFT'` or `'RIGHT'` string values?

(Note: I'd rather not use enums here. I want to find out why this doesn't work.)

It seems to work if I add `as Direction` to the end:

```
// This is fine:
this.direction = ['LEFT', 'RIGHT'][Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)] as Direction;
```

Comment: `['LEFT', 'RIGHT']` is just `string[]`, so indexing into it gives you `string` and (to answer your title question) most strings are neither `'LEFT'` nor `'RIGHT'`. Use an explicit type or `const` assertion.

Answer (score 2):

Per default TypeScript infers the array literal `["LEFT", "RIGHT"]` as `string[]`. You can force TypeScript to infer the array with the most specific type available (=`["LEFT", "RIGHT"]`) by using a [`const`-assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgJwgY2HA9gOygXigIgBkBRAMQBV8oAfAgJQEkBxACUoG4AoZAGwEMAzgNgBXZAGsecTAHMoAb05QoAE0Qo0WAFyx1qDJi5KoyLAOAIxwdAgAUASgXHlwABZwBAOjVJ9WXFC2ANpEZJQANPTMbPgAulCCJmbA9kHOylAAsnxungBmPOg2ttm5CHyYKugAtg5QAFRQAEz26bFcygC+nN1AA).

```
type Direction = "LEFT" | "RIGHT";
class Duckling {
  direction: Direction;

  constructor() {
    this.direction = (["LEFT", "RIGHT"] as const)[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
    ];
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgJwgY2HA9gOygXigIgBkBRAMQBV8oAfAgJQEkBxACUoG4AoZAGwEMAzgNgBXZAGsecTAHMoAb05QoAE0Qo0WAFyx1qDJi5KoyLAOAIxwdAgAUASgXHlwABZwBAOjVJ9WXFC2ANpEZJQANPTMbPgAulCCJmbA9kHOylAAsnxungBmPOg2ttm5CHyYKugAtg5QAFRQAEz26bFcygC+nN1AA)